# Python Jupyter Notebook loops while writing output to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, printing, jupyter-notebook

A jupyter notebook cell is calculating some things and prints the results.
I would like to print everything into a text file. The text file is created and written. But maybe the cell isnt properly closed as it never comes to an running end? Where is my mistake?

The code:

```
with open(path_out + day_number + 'factsheet.txt', 'w') as fs:
    sys.stdout = fs 
    print("Fact Sheet:")
    Lat_start = df.Wgs84Latitude[df.index.min()] 
    Lon_start = df.Wgs84Longitude[df.index.min()]
    print("Coordinates: " , Lat_start,'°N , ', Lon_start,'°E')
    print("Min. Humidity: " + "{:12.2f}".format(df.humidity.min()) + " %")
    print("Max. Humidity: " + "{:12.2f}".format(df.humidity.max()) + " %")
    print("Min. Temperature: " + "{:9.2f}".format(df.temperature.min()) + " °C")
    print("Max. Temperature: " + "{:9.2f}".format(df.temperature.max()) + " °C")
    sys.stdout = original_stdout # Reset the standard output to its original value
    fs.close()
```

Any hint for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works without tapping into a loop, but I still do not understand why the above code leads to loop the cell.

My "workaround":

```
fs = open(path_out + day_number + '_factsheet.txt', 'w') 
Lat_start = df.Wgs84Latitude[df.index.min()] 
Lon_start = df.Wgs84Longitude[df.index.min()]
fs.write("Coordinates: " + str(Lat_start) + '°N , ' + str(Lon_start) + '°E\n\n')
fs.write("Min. Humidity: " + "{:12.2f}".format(df.humidity.min()) + " %\n")
fs.write("Max. Humidity: " + "{:12.2f}".format(df.humidity.max()) + " %\n")
fs.write("Min. Temperature: " + "{:9.2f}".format(df.Temperature.min()) + " °C\n")
fs.write("Max. Temperature: " + "{:9.2f}".format(df.Temperature.max()) + " °C\n")
fs.close() 
print("Export successful")
```

Remark: This solution accepts only the "+"-symbol to add several contents in one write-break and I had to add th "\n" to insert a line feed which was not neccessary in the "print" solution.
But it works :-)